# log4j - logs not written to file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I've seen questions about it, but none of it helped me.
I'm using log4j, but as it works fine on console, it doesn't write anything to declared files. What is more, files were created, but nothing is saved in them. 
Code:

```
#default
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,console

#Console Appender
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{hh:mm:ss}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n

#Custom assignments
log4j.logger.controller=DEBUG,console
log4j.logger.service=DEBUG,console
log4j.logger.dao=DEBUG,console

#Disable additivity
log4j.additivity.controller=false
log4j.additivity.service=false
log4j.additivity.dao=false

#MyLogger
log4j.logger.classPath.myClass = INFO, CACHE

log4j.appender.CACHE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CACHE.File = ./logs/cache.log
log4j.appender.CACHE.bufferedIO = false
log4j.appender.CACHE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.CACHE.Threshold=info
log4j.appender.CACHE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CACHE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{hh:mm:ss}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n
```

I'm sure that logger is defined properly, because when `additivity=false`, logs are not showed in console as expected. And when `log4j.logger.myClass = INFO, CACHE, console` is added as well, logs are showed in console again. So logger declaration seems fine. So why are they not showed in log file?

I'm using `org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(myClass.class).info('msg')` syntax to use logger. 
`org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("classPath.myClass").info('msg')` is not working either.

When trying `log4j.rootLogger=INFO,console,CACHE` also nothing appears in the file.

Comment: try changing to log4j.rootLogger=INFO,console

Comment: Not working. And according to this source: http://www.goldenline.pl/ramka/aHR0cDovL2xvZ2dpbmcuYXBhY2hlLm9yZy9sb2c0ai8xLjIvbWFudWFsLmh0bWw= it doesn't matter because my logger has its level defined.

Comment: since, the level is defined for MyClass, the level wouldn't get inherited from parent

Answer (score 1):

The logger name is specified wrongly. Please change it as follows

```
#MyLogger
log4j.logger.MyClass = INFO, CACHE
```

instead of

```
#MyLogger
log4j.logger.myClass = INFO, CACHE
```

**MyClass** is wrongly denoted as **myClass**. You can also make the logger instantiation as follows

```
Logger.getLogger("MyClass").info('msg');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, MyClass is just an example, not actual name. MyClass means classpath+className or just a classpath. But changing it to just a short name (like myClass) and using it with Logger.getLogger("myClass") still doesn't work.

Comment: Logger can be instantiated with name or using package. Please make the question complete. so, it will be easy to help

Comment: OK, I changed question a little and I hope I made it clear, that declaretion of logger is fine. The problem is only with writing logs to file.

Comment: so, you have configured the level and appender for package 'classPath.myClass' as INFO and CACHE? am i right?

Comment: `log4j.logger.classPath.myClass = INFO, CACHE` - like in a code above

Comment: did you check the value of logger.getLevel()?